# What is causing this issue when trying to get yahoo_fin to return prices for a list of tickers?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spyder, finance, yahoo-finance

I have a list of tickers that I want to retrieve the prices for by running the following:

```
from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si
for x in watchlist:
    print(si.get_live_price(x))
```

When I run this I get the following error:

> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/User/OneDrive/Documents/Stuff/fluff 2.py', wdir='C:/Users/User/OneDrive/Documents/Stuff')
>
> File
>   "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 705, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 102, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/User/OneDrive/Documents/Stuff/fluff 2.py", line 46,
>   in 
>       print(si.get_live_price(x))
>
> File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yahoo_fin\stock_info.py", line
>   338, in get_live_price
>       df = get_data(ticker, end_date = pd.Timestamp.today() + pd.DateOffset(10))
>
> File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yahoo_fin\stock_info.py", line
>   68, in get_data
>       temp = loads(needed)
>
> ValueError: Expected object or value

However, when I refer to a ticker directly, it runs normally:

```
print(si.get_live_price('tsla'))
```

**348.8399963378906**

What could be causing this issue? Is it due to me using a different html parser than that used with yahoo_fin in an earlier part of the code?

Comment: So, watchlist is a list of strings, and all of them work when you test them directly? Are you sure about that?

Comment: Now it's not working at all, the TSLA example I provided resulted in the same error message instead of the price value it showed before. Perhaps I need a new source of price data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, It gives you complete dataframe for last 6 months data

```
import yfinance as yf
for x in ['TSLA','AAPL']:
    data = yf.download( tickers = x)
    print(data['Close'][-1])
```

Output :

```
348.8399963378906
268.4800109863281
```

If you want last 6 month data then you can store individual dataframe. In above case I have printed only last index as you wanted LTP.

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be fixed now in the latest version of yahoo_fin (0.8.4).  It was due to a change in Yahoo Finance's structure.  See here for news about recent updates: http://theautomatic.net/2019/12/16/updates-to-yahoo_fin-package/